# ESLINT Unexpected top-level property "import/order" error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app, eslintrc

I'm trying to create a rule to have a one empty line between internal and external imports.

.eslintrc.json:

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "env": {
      "es6": true,
      "node": true,
      "jest/globals": true,
      "browser": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
      "sourceType": "module",
      "ecmaVersion": 2019,
      "project": "tsconfig.json",
      "ecmaFeatures": {
          "jsx": true
      }
  },
  "rules": {
    "import/order": [
    "error",
    {
      "groups": [["builtin", "external"]],
      "newlines-between": "always"
    }
  ]
  }
}
```

I have the following error:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

ESLint configuration in .eslintrc.json is invalid:
    - Unexpected top-level property "import/order".
```

Comment: hi perhaps a dependency https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65602807/eslint-import-order-react-typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified an existing project with a similar eslint config to use your rule.  It is working nicely.  I have a suspicion your issue is that you don't have an `extends` property that includes the import rules.  Here's my eslint config:

```js
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        node: true,
    },
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:import/warnings', // <--- note this inclusion here
    ],
    rules: {
        'import/order': [
            'error',
            {
                groups: [['builtin', 'external']],
                'newlines-between': 'always',
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

When I run the linter, I get the expected error you want:

```
13:1  error  There should be at least one empty line between import groups  import/order
```

I would try playing with your `extends` property.  I have some stuff in there you may not need at all, and I *dont* have the jsx stuff for this particular project, but hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: thanks a lot I've got the following error `Failed to load plugin 'prettier' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier'
Require stack:
- ../.eslintrc.js`

Comment: @AlinaKhachatrian I'll remove those from my answer.  I use prettier, which uses those entries in the eslint config to integrate with eslint.  Highly recommended!

Comment: lol I do use it too as an extension in vs code ...

Comment: @AlinaKhachatrian, glad this helped.  Sometimes eslint and prettier fight with eachother about code formatting, so having eslint *extent* prettier can be helpful sometimes.  Something to keep in mind for the future.  You can just `npm i -D eslint-plugin-prettier` to get that working if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Install this dependency:  `eslint-import-resolver-typescript`

```
# npm
npm i -D eslint-plugin-import @typescript-eslint/parser eslint-import-resolver-typescript

# yarn
yarn add -D eslint-plugin-import @typescript-eslint/parser eslint-import-resolver-typescript
```

And add `import` to your plugins :

```
 "plugins": ["import"],
```

[eslint-import-resolver-typescript](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/eslint-import-resolver-typescript)

Comment: thanks I've installed the suggested dependency, now I have   `Line 1:1:  Definition for rule 'import/order' was not found  import/order

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.`

Comment: you'll need to add `import` to your plugins